# Different types of Azure Active Directory when making integration

Tags: active-directory, integration, office365

My application is building an integration with Office 365 to be able to sync users from Office 365 through APIs of Azure AD by adding my application to 'Applications' of Active Directory in Azure portal.

When creating a new Active Directory in Azure AD, I see that there are 3 types of AD: Directory, Access control, Multi-factor auth provider

[AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtosA.png)

We tested successfully with the first type 'Directory'. Just worry the rest types of AD will have some specific configurations that can impact my integration. But I dont have enough budget to subscribe them to make full test. If someone has knowledge about these two type Active Directories, could you help to share or provide me some advises? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to sync users from Office 365 to your local storage.

Azure Active Directory, Azure Access Control Service and Azure Multi-Factor Authentication Service all provide the user authentication service. 
But unlike Azure Active Directory, the access control service and Multi-Factor authentication service do not store the users.

The **Microsoft Azure Access Control Service** provides the Federated Identity service (for example, the user can log in the app with his/her google account).

**Azure Multi-factor authentication** is a method of verifying who you are that requires the use of more than just a username and password. It provides a second layer of security to user sign-ins and transactions (the user could be stored on the on-premise AD or other LDAP servers).

For users sync scenario, you only need to handle the type "Directory".

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey so much for your detail response. I feel more convenience to ship that feature after read through your explanation. It's very much appreciated.